# Exported variable in bashrc file not visible when running as another user

Tags: bash, ubuntu

On Ubuntu 20.04LTS:

- Create a dummy user.
- Create a short script that appends an exported variable to the new user's `.bashrc`, then sources that `.bashrc` and tries to use the variable.
- Run the script as the new user.

Why is the variable not set?

```sh
> adduser --gecos ',,,' --disabled-password foouser
[...output...]
> cat > /tmp/bootstrap.sh <<EOF
  echo 'export FOO=foo' >> /home/foouser/.bashrc
  . /home/foouser/.bashrc
  echo 'sourced foouser bashrc'
  set | grep FOO
EOF
> chmod a+x /tmp/bootstrap.sh
> su - foouser -c /tmp/bootstrap.sh
[...output does not include FOO...]
> deluser --remove-home foouser
```

Comment: `.bashrc` isn't really the place for setting environment variables anyway. Do that in `.bash_profile`, since any other interactive shell is going to inherit from the login shell anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `.bashrc` is configure *explicitly* to only run for interactive shells. Look at the top of `/home/foouser/.bashrc`:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

If you add a `set -x` to your `/tmp/bootstrap.sh` script, you will see when you execute it the following:

```
+ echo 'export FOO=foo'
+ . /home/foouser/.bashrc
++ case $- in
++ return
+ echo 'sourced foouser bashrc'
sourced foouser bashrc
+ set
+ grep FOO
```

There you can see it hits the `return` command in the case statement.

You can force an interactive shell with the `-i` option:

```
root@ed3085a447ad:/# su - foouser -c 'bash -i -c /tmp/bootstrap.sh'
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
sourced foouser bashrc
FOO=foo
```